# Database SQL server migration from 2008 to 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Any datatype or component or join syntax changes are happen in Query level?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For `JOIN`, no. This is pretty straight forward ANSI Standards.

For TSQL Syntax, sure. There's a lot of new features. Most of these came out in 2012 For example:

- [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`LAST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`TRY_PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`EO_MONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- etc...

There is also a a list of what's new for the DB Engine, BI, SSIS, Replication, and SSRS, performance (like MAXDOP for DBCC CHECKDB), new DMVs, etc. [You can find that all here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb500435(v=sql.120).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

These are all valid answers.  However you should run the SQL 2014 Upgrade Advisor.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn236457%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It will show you all Views, Procedures, etc... that have discontinued functionality.